# The volume of the salt at any instant

Tags: calculus

> An inverted conical funnel is full of salt. The salt is allowed to leave by a small hole in the vertex. It leaves at a constant rate of $6 \ \text{cm}^3 \ \text s^{-1}$.
>
> Given that the angle of the cone between the slanting edge and the vertical is $30^\circ$,
> show that the volume of the salt is $\frac 19\pi h^3$, where $h$ is the height of salt at time $t$ seconds.
> Show that the rate of change of the height of the salt in the funnel is inversely proportional to $h^2$. Write down the differential equation relating $h$ and $t$.

My turn:

$$\tan{30^\circ} = \frac{r}{h}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}= \frac{r}{h} , r= \frac{h}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$V= \pi r^2 h = \pi \bigg(\frac{h}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)^2 h = \frac{1}{3} \pi h^3$$
I think had no mistake for the first required but it does not match what is written in the text!

Is the problem with me or it is just a misprinted ?

Comment: The volume of a cone is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$. You missed out the factor $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you @almagest